# How to update only fields in a form that are NOT blank

Tags: php

I'm VERY new to MySQL and PHP and have been teaching myself for sometime.  I'm not expecting anyone to write my code for me, but I am looking for some suggestions on how best to proceed with this script.

I have a set of users that can update their "skill level" on a particular set of products.  At the moment, I have all that working.  However, I don't want the user to have to update every skill level each time they submit.

So, in other words, I want them to be able to leave a field blank, but populate other fields with their skill level, thus only updating the fields they have input.

I'm doing this all on a dev server so here is my code that I'm currently working with.

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","time2start") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("joomla_dev_15") or die ("Database Connection Failed");
$user = $_POST['user'];
$USP = $_POST['USP'];
$USPV = $_POST['USPV'];
$VSP = $_POST['VSP'];
echo "$user<br />";
echo "$USP<br />";
echo "$USPV<br />";
echo "$VSP<br />";

$query = "UPDATE `joomla_dev_15`.`enterprise_storage` SET  `$user` =  '$USP' WHERE `enterprise_storage`.`id` = 1;";
if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo "updated<br />";
}else{
    echo "FAILURE";
}

$query = "UPDATE  `joomla_dev_15`.`enterprise_storage` SET  `$user` =  '$USPV' WHERE  `enterprise_storage`.`id` =2;";
if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo "updated<br />";
}else{
    echo "FAILURE";
}

$query = "UPDATE  `joomla_dev_15`.`enterprise_storage` SET  `$user` =  '$VSP' WHERE  `enterprise_storage`.`id` =3;";
if( mysql_query($query) )
{
    echo "updated<br />";
}else{
    echo "FAILURE";
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1 For the right attitude, don't have time to help right now.

Comment: have you considered that if a user intentionally leaves that field blank? if the user makes it blank (because he wants it cleared), your script won't update to field right?

Comment: you'll have to build a mysql statement anyway, so just iterate through the values and only include non-blank ones in the sql query. Also, consider populating the form with their current corresponding database values

Comment: Although @Joseph is not explicitly saying it, I think he's right; normally a field on a form would be pre-filled on page-load with the information they have entered previously so the visitor can either change or delete it and submit the form. Then all fields would have to be saved in the database, also the empty ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding this fully, but checking you variables before the UPDATE statement should be enough.

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$USP = $_POST['USP']; // Make sure to escape this

if (!empty(trim($USP))) { // Added a trim so that when space is entered, it will still be considered empty
  $query = "UPDATE `joomla_dev_15`.`enterprise_storage` SET  `$user` =  '$USP' WHERE `enterprise_storage`.`id` = 1;";
  if(mysql_query($query))
  {
    echo "updated<br />";
  }else{
    echo "FAILURE";
  }
}
else {
  echo "Empty String. Nothing to Do"
}
```

Comment: You're right, I don't think I explained this very well.  Perhaps the best way to describe what I'm trying to do, is bring up a particular user's set of "Skills" in a form.  In the form, it will pull their current skill level entries that exist in the database and essentially make make the "default value" of the text box the same as what they currently have.  This way, the user can update either all or 1 of their skill levels as they see fit without having to completely fill out the form over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out in a way that was satisfactory for me.

Keep in mind, that this code is not necessarily sanitized or secure from malicious attacks, this is simply a dev server so I could prove the concept, and I WILL come back later and secure it.

Also, I've taught myself, so this is most likely not the most efficient way to do this

In order to get the current default values of the user's skills, I had to run this query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id , user FROM enterprise_storage WHERE id =1");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This allowed me to assign a variable to each row that was returned based on this specific query.  So, in this case, the person (named "user" in this example) would return a skill level for Product ID "1"

Once I ran this same query for the few items I wanted to assign variables, I could then place this in my html form as the default value for each text box:

```
Please enter your skill level on the following products:</br>
USP: <input type="text" name="USP" value=<?php echo $row1[user]?> /><br />
USPV: <input type="text" name="USPV" value=<?php echo $row2[user]?> /><br />
VSP: <input type="text" name="VSP" value=<?php echo $row3[user]?> /><br />
```

I've omitted the rest of the HTML, because its not relevant right now.
In the end, this solves my problem as it places a default value into the form field, and thus the user doesn't need to update that value if they don't want to.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Check if the form values are blank and do not post them into the database if they are - also, you really need to look at cleansing user input before putting it into the database.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for example.

Comment: wow, two downvotes?  That's unexpected.  You could at least tell me what you don't like about my answer.

Comment: I didnt downvote but I'd say that you need to think your answer through and provide a little more detail, at the moment it is nothing more than comment worthy.

Comment: I agree that cleansing needs to occur, I'm just not at that point yet.  I see what you mean about the blank input, but I actually don't want to allow any blank input, and I'm looking to solve that by my comment to adidasadida.  Don't think you deserved a down-vote for it though :)